# Force iPad to sync with only one Mac

Tags: itunes, ipad, data-synchronization

I have two Macs sitting on my desk: a MacBook Pro (work computer) and an iMac (personal). I sync my iPad 2 with the iMac where all of my media and other stuff lives. Since the advent of iOS 5 and OTA syncing, however, the iPad has taken to syncing with both Macs, choosing (seemingly) randomly between the two when powered on and plugged in within WiFi range. The trouble is, when it syncs with the MBP, it generates dozens of "error while syncing" dialogs (which take awhile to individually dismiss) on the iPad because (I'm assuming) none of my content, apps, etc. are on that machine.

Is there a way I can stop the MacBook Pro from syncing with the iPad?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iTunes on your MacBook Pro go to **Preferences**, then **Devices**, and then select the checkbox that says **"Prevent iPods, iPhones, and iPads from syncing automatically"**; that should solve your problem.